# Как создать проверку переменной на наличие значения?

Tags: javascript, таймер

```js
function startRotateTo5DegEachSec()
{
// Сделать проверку что таймер не создан if(rotationTimer содержит значение) { 
 rotationTimer=setInterval("rotateInput(5);",1000);//выполняет код много раз
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rotationTimer = null;
function startRotateTo5DegEachSec() {
  if(!rotationTimer) { 
    rotationTimer = setInterval(rotateInput, 1000, 5);
  }
}

function rotateInput(angle) {
  console.log(angle);
}

startRotateTo5DegEachSec();
startRotateTo5DegEachSec();
startRotateTo5DegEachSec();
```

Comment: Как диалог немых. Без слов, только код. Только хардкор